# expect exiting after expect{send} statement

Tags: bash, expect

when I run this script that I wrote to help installing AUR packages:

```
enter #!/bin/bash
#bash
function GO() {
    pack="$1"
    cower -ddf $pack
    cd "/home/$USER/applications/$pack"
    expect -c " set timeout -1
        eval spawn makepkg -Ascfi --noconfirm
        expect -nocase \"password for $USER:\" {send \"$pass\r\"}
        interact;"
    cd "../"

}
package="$1"
echo "I need your password for this, can I have it please?"
read -s pass
cd "/home/$USER/applications"

if [ "$package" == "update" ]
then
    file="/home/$USER/applications/update.pkgs"
    cower -u > file 
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        package=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f2)
        GO $package
    done <"$file"
else
    GO $package
fi

echo "have a good day."

exit 0
```

sometimes interact just stoppes after it enters the password and it just echos "have a good day." and exits. am I doing something wrong? timeout is < 0, I have interact aftet the expect statement, anything I am missing?

Comment: use `expect -d -c "..."` and see what's happening.

Comment: before it quits it says it got a EOF "send: sending "{insert password here}\r" to { exp4 }
spawn id exp4 sent <\r\n>

interact: received eof from spawn_id exp0
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = -c  argv[3] =  set timeout -1
   eval spawn makepkg -Ascfi --noconfirm
   expect -nocase "password for jaap:" {send "{insert password here}\r"}
   interact;  
set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
have a good day."
I'll ask the arch linux forums about this, sorry for the late reply I havnt received any updates untill today.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see is that the password might have a quote in it. You might want to do this:

```
env _user="$USER" _pass="$pass" expect <<'END'
    set timeout -1
    spawn makepkg -Ascfi --noconfirm
    expect -nocase "password for $env(_user):" {
        send -- $env(_pass)
        send "\r"
    }
    interact
END
```

No need to `eval spawn` here.

Using the quoted heredoc makes the code easier to read too.

Comment: no I dont have any quotes, numbers and letters(capital and non capital).